# How can I run my node js script automatically using scheduler

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a nodejs file.

Currently i need to schedule the task to run that file automatically at multiple occasion in a single day.

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');

var rule = new schedule.RecurrenceRule();
rule.hour = 12;

var j = schedule.scheduleJob(rule, function(){
  console.log('Hello world!');
});
```

Comment: you can use a cron job instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation say date and not day

RecurrenceRule properties:

- second
- minute
- hour
- date
- month
- year
- dayOfWeek

https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you need to set the date, not the day, but either way, setting the date = 1 doesn't make the time interval equal 1 day, it makes the date that this rule occurs on equal to 1. In this case, because the week starts on sunday and it begins at 0, you set the rule to occur every Monday at midnight.

For the scheduler, everything defaults to 0 unless you set it. Because you set the rule.date = 1, everything else, the minute, hour, etc all =0.

If you want it to occur every day, you would need to set a range of days:

```
rule.dayOfWeek = [new schedule.Range(0, 6)];
```

Then you would need to set the time that this occurs at. For example, if you wanted it to occur at 10:30 am, you would set:

```
rule.minute = 30
rule.hour = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this

```
var j = schedule.scheduleJob('0 0 0 * * *', function(){
  console.log('for 12:00 am daily' );
});
```

and for particular time use this

```
0 30 8 * * *
```

8:30 am